# Google artifact registry gradle plugin returns bad request on publish

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I'm publishing a kotlin multiplatform project to Google's artifact registry using their Gradle plugin, publishing both the Kotlin and JVM source sets.

Every time I publish a new version, Gradle throws the following error:

`Could not PUT 'https://europe-west1-maven.pkg.dev/***/***/***/***/***/2.0.0/sdk-2.0.0.jar'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request`

Weirdly though, both packages do get uploaded to artifact registry, and I'm able to pull them in different projects just fine.

I assumed this was a bug in the Gradle plugin, but this has been going on for over a year now with multiple updates so I don't think that's the case.

Am I doing something wrong? Anyone else having this issue? Or is this maybe really a bug in the plugin.

Comment: can you try  creating a repository with the RELEASE version policy or no version policy.

Comment: Have you checked my above comment.

If the artifact that you are pushing follows the "RELEASE" pattern. Create a repository with the RELEASE version policy or none version policy.

If The artifact that you are pushing follows the "RELEASE" pattern. At the same time the repository that you are trying to push to is of "SNAPSHOT" version policy, you will get the error message because It will accept only snapshot versions.